# Segmentation error on array initialization in c++

Tags: segmentation-fault

Hello I am new to c++ and I have a program I need to write, it's about 2 objects, char pointer and array of objects. So the program was running ok, but then started to crash and I added some `cout` to see where it was crashing and then after I deleted them it started to give me Segmentation error. And I changed from VS Code to Dev-C++ and there it showed me the error. Any suggestions what is the problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

class Point {
 protected:
   int y, x;
   char *name;

  public:
   Point()
    {
     int newX, newY;
     char *newName = new char[20];
     cout << "Enter value for X: ";
     cin >> newX;
     setX(newX);

     cout << "Enter value for Y: ";
     cin >> newY;
     setY(newY);

     cout << "Enter name: ";
     cin >>setw(20) >> newName;
    
     cout << "Eror name";
     setName(newName);
 }
 int getX() { return x; }
 int getY() { return y; }
 char getName() { return *name;  }
 void setX(int new_x) { x = new_x; }
 void setY(int new_y) { y = new_y; }
 void setName(char *newName) { name = newName; }
 void showXY() { cout << "\nX: " << getX() << "\nY: " << getY(); }
 ~Point(){};
  };

 class Circle{
   int radius;
   Point point;
  
    public:
    
    Circle() {
        int r;
        cout << "Enter radius: ";
        cin >> r;
        setRadius(r); 
    }

 int getRadius() { return radius; }
 void setRadius(int r) 
  { 
    radius = r;
    cout << "Radius " << radius << "\n";
  }
 void showAll() {
    cout << "Name: " << point.getName();
    point.showXY();
    cout << "\nRaduis: " << getRadius();
}
~Circle(){};};

 int main()
{   
  Circle circles0;
  Circle circles1;

  Circle circles[] = { circles0, circles1 };

  for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
  {
    int r = circles[i].getRadius();
    if( r > 4)
    {
        circles[i].showAll();   
    }
  }
return 0;}
```

Edit: So I did some configurations on Dev-C++ and now the code runs there, but in VS code doesn't. What I did was to configure the debugger in Dev-C++ and in more detail:

1. Tools -> Compiler Options
2. Settings -> Generate debugging information -> to "Yes"
3. Clicked "Ok"
   And now my code works in Dev-C++.

Comment: What inputs do you give your program to cause it to crash?

Comment: I am not trying to crash the code if that is what you're saying, for int types I use int and for the char pointer I use letters, you can try with these: X:8 Y:6 Name: jo radius: 6. All my testing look like this.